# Cannot connect to mongodb container from linux host

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have the following Dockerfile that only installs mongodb 3

```
# Start with docker's base ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2

# Mongodb prerequisite
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

# Update package sources
RUN apt-get -y update

# Install Mongodb binaries
RUN apt-get -y install mongodb-org

# Copy configuratio file
COPY mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf

# Create mongo data path (will be mapped to a volume on host machine later on)
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
RUN chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db

# Expose MongoDB port
EXPOSE 27017

# Run mongo with mongodb user
USER mongodb

# Run mongod using provided configuration file
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
CMD ["--config", "/etc/mongod.conf"]
```

I create the image with

```
sudo docker build -t mongod .
```

I run the container with

```
sudo docker run -d -P mongod
```

And verify it's started

```
> sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
43c75e7e44b3        mongod:latest       "/usr/bin/mongod --c   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:49165->27017/tcp   silly_mccarthy
```

When I run a mongo client from the container, it can connect without any error:

```
> sudo docker exec -ti 43c75e7e44b3 bash

$ mongo

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
....
```

My host is a Ubuntu 14.04 box and the network interfaces / bridges are

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 63:54:7b:f3:47:33
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          ....
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:2f:e3:64:ae:7c
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ....
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          ....
```

From my host, I cannot connect to the mongod container

```
> mongo --port 49165

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:49165/test
2015-03-21T18:14:55.936+0100 I NETWORK  Socket recv() errno:104     Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:49165
2015-03-21T18:14:55.936+0100 I NETWORK  SocketException: remote:   127.0.0.1:49165 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:49165]
2015-03-21T18:14:55.936+0100 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2015-03-21T18:14:55.937+0100 E QUERY    Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:49165 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 }
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

Is there something I'm missing here ?

Comment: Check wether `mongod` is bound to 127.0.0.1 only in your `mongod.conf`. If yes, comment this line out. Furthermore, you need to connect to your comtainer's IP, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks, this was the bindIp option in the config file that was set to 127.0.01. Could you make this comment an answer ?

Comment: Done and beefed it up a bit to hold additional information.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's default configuration is to bind `mongod` to the IP of `localhost`. Search for the following line in your `mongod.conf`:

```
bindIp = 127.0.0.1
```

If you comment this line out using a hash like this

```
# bindIp = 127.0.0.1
```

then `mongod` will bind to *all* IPs available during startup. If you set a specific IP like this

```
bindIp = 192.168.0.42
```

then `mongod` binds only to this specific IP address and will only be available to hosts which can access that IP on the specified port.